# Conditional row sum in R

Tags: r

```
    a   avalue  b   bvalue
1  12   yes     3   no
2  13   yes     3   yes
3  14   no      2   no
4  NA   no      1   no
5  16   NA      1   yes
```

I'm trying to count the total number of **yes** in each row, so the output would be like this:

```
   Count
1  12
2  16
3  0
4  0
5  1
```

Here is my solution which is not working.
`df$count <- rowSums(data[data(3) | data(5) == 'yes',c(2,4)], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: So row 2 would be 16 right?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? "Show me how to solve this coding problem" is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: yes row 2 would be 16

Comment: `with(d, a * aval %in% "yes" + b * bval %in% "yes")`. Here the result of row 4 is `NA` (which may be considered more appropriate than setting it to `0`).

Comment: @Henrik how can I implement this?

Comment: Just change "d" to the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

OP has edited the post to include headers on the input data, and judging from the comments, it seems that OP wants the solution to scale to multiple column pairs. Here's a solution in base R that should do that:

```r
raw <- "
   a   avalue  b   bvalue
1  12   yes     3   no
2  13   yes     3   yes
3  14   no      2   no
4  NA   no      1   no
5  16   NA      1   yes "

df <- read.table(text = raw, header = TRUE)

use <- endsWith(colnames(df), "value")
df[use] <- ifelse(df[use] == "yes", TRUE, FALSE)
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
rowSums(df[use] * df[!use])
#>  1  2  3  4  5 
#> 12 16  0  0  1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Original post:**

Another take:

```r
raw <- "1  12   yes     3   no
2  13   yes     3   yes
3  14   no      2   no
4  NA   no      1   no
5  16   NA      1   yes"

df <- read.table(text = raw)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

df %>%
  setNames(c("row", "value_first", "use_first", "value_second", "use_second")) %>%
  pivot_longer(!row, names_to = c(".value", "column"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  replace_na(list(value = 0, use = "no")) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(value * (use == "yes")))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>     row total
#> * <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1    12
#> 2     2    16
#> 3     3     0
#> 4     4     0
#> 5     5     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Or using base R, you can simply do element-wise multiplication for the rows that satisfy your condition on the value column, and then apply `rowSums()`:

```r
raw <- "1  12   yes     3   no
2  13   yes     3   yes
3  14   no      2   no
4  NA   no      1   no
5  16   NA      1   yes"

df <- read.table(text = raw)

rowSums((!is.na(df[,c(3,5)])&df[,c(3,5)]=="yes") * df[,c(2,4)], na.rm=TRUE)
#> [1] 12 16  0  0  1

## Explanation:
# 1) Select relevant rows
(rows_select <- !is.na(df[,c(3,5)])&df[,c(3,5)]=="yes")
#>         V3    V5
#> [1,]  TRUE FALSE
#> [2,]  TRUE  TRUE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE
#> [4,] FALSE FALSE
#> [5,] FALSE  TRUE

# 2) multiply by the columns with the data:
(rows_sel_val <- rows_select * df[,c(2,4)])
#>   V2 V4
#> 1 12  0
#> 2 13  3
#> 3  0  0
#> 4 NA  0
#> 5  0  1

# 3) Apply rowSums
rowSums(rows_sel_val, na.rm=TRUE)
#> [1] 12 16  0  0  1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Create a new data frame df0 that has 0 where each NA in df is and then use the indicated formula on it.  No packages are used.

```
df0 <- replace(df, is.na(df), 0)
transform(df, count = with(df0, a * (avalue == "yes") + b * (bvalue == "yes")))
```

giving:

```
   a avalue b bvalue count
1 12    yes 3     no    12
2 13    yes 3    yes    16
3 14     no 2     no     0
4 NA     no 1     no     0
5 16   <NA> 1    yes     1
```

**2)** or if there are more than just a and b then this gives the same result but handles any number of columns.  ok picks out the a, b, etc. columns and !ok picks out the avalue, bvalue, etc. columns.  Note that R will automatically recycle ok and !ok to a length equal to the number of columns.

```
ok <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
transform(df, count = rowSums(df[ok] * (df[!ok] == "yes"), na.rm = TRUE))
```

**2a)** Using the collapse package, a variation on (2) is to use num_vars and cat_vars which pick out the numeric and categorical columns.

Note that if any of the numeric columns are all NA then they must be set using NA_real_ or NA_integer_ and not just NA since num_vars is extracting columns by type.  This can be checked by ensuring that logi_vars(df) has no columns (since an ordinary NA is logical) or else just use (2) if it is possible that any column is all NA.

```
library(collapse)

transform(df, count = rowSums(num_vars(df0) * (cat_vars(df0) == "yes"), na.rm = TRUE))
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
    a   avalue  b   bvalue
1  12   yes     3   no
2  13   yes     3   yes
3  14   no      2   no
4  NA   no      1   no
5  16   NA      1   yes"
df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: can we make it dynamic? so if we had more columns like c d e f, wouldn't need to write all of them?

Comment: @Mohammad Regarding "_if we had more columns like c d e f, wouldn't need to write all of them_", please add that information to your question - remember to always provide examples of sufficient complexity, not more, not less. Now people may have spent time on hardcoded solutions, which may be useless given a more complex data set. Cheers

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Nice to see some `collapse` functions! I have started to dig around in the (very nice) docs - seem to include many extremely useful convenience functions. Remains to be seen if its more general functions/concept manage to gain a wider audience in the `data.table` / `dplyr` hegemony. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tidy my data and calculate the sum by group, using the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-read.table(text = "1  12   yes     3   no
2  13   yes     3   yes
3  14   no      2   no
4  NA   no      1   no
5  16   NA      1   yes")

bind_rows(df[1:3], setNames(df[c(1,4:5)], paste0("V",1:3))) %>%
group_by(V1, V3) %>%
summarise(sum(V2, na.rm = TRUE))

#> Groups:   V1 [5]
#>     V1 V3    `sum(V2, na.rm = TRUE)`
#>  <int> <chr>                   <int>
#>1     1 no                          3
#>2     1 yes                        12
#>3     2 yes                        16
#>4     3 no                         16
#>5     4 no                          1
#>6     5 yes                         1
#>7     5 <NA>                       16
```

Comment: the usage of setNames and the selction of columns naturally only works in this example - you will need to adjust it to the actual structure of your data of course